# Scroll Bar Substitute for Mobile - tabbed areas

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

So I have tabbed areas within a site I'm developing, because of my layout I need to keep all my tabbed areas having the same height. At first I thought, "oh, cool, I'll just do `display: scroll;` and have a scrollbar".

But I really don't want to have this for mobile. **Could anyone suggest a mobile friendly solution to my problem of having scrolling content within a fixed tabbed area height in mobile. Or maybe just enabling touch scroll with scroll bar?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a mobile website a while back and spent a while trying to get scrollable areas within the page. But, I eventually came to the realisation that it wasn't very user friendly. I wanted people to be able to use my site with just their thumb, so they could use it one-handed. I think that having small scrollable areas within a mobile (ie - small screen) website isn't a great user experience.

What I ended up doing was just letting the browser deal with the scrolling and it turned out it did a great job!

A possible approach you could take would be to page your tabs, similar to the way that the apple app store works on mobile devices. That way you wouldn't need to worry about the user having to scroll back to the top in order to switch to other tabs.

Comment: Any maybe just no overflow:scroll at mobile viewport? hm.. sounds like an idea - too bad there's not a cooler solution. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Would the jQM ScrollView option work?

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview